# Script Indices Change Between Operations

Tags: modeling, python, bmesh

I have an issue with my code where randomly in the middle the indices of faces, edges, and vertices switch between two different patterns. It's not randomized, and yet it isn't consistent where the same indices appear after an operation like the rest of my script. I've noticed this happens when I remove vertices from the model (previously I had assumed it was during merge vertices but after significant testing this came back to be untrue). Furthermore, the two "variations" of how the indices are laid out toggle back and forth at random. The correct order appears most of the time, but sometimes twice in a row, or every 7th-11th iteration, the incorrect order is modelled. How can I avoid this? I've tried using BMesh (used in many functions such as mergeVerts(), selectVert(), etc...) after not having luck with BPY and the problem has persisted.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
    size=cabinetHeight, 
    enter_editmode=True, 
    align='WORLD', 
    location=(0, 0, 0), 
    scale=(1, 1, 1))

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

selectFace(2) #move in -x by half of difference of width

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=((cabinetHeight-cabinetWidth)/-2, -0, -0))
selectFace(0) #move in +x by half of difference of width
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=((cabinetHeight-cabinetWidth)/2, -0, -0))
selectFace(1) #move in -y by half of difference of width
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0,(cabinetHeight-cabinetDepth)/-2, -0)) 
selectFace(3) #move in +y by half of difference of width
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0,(cabinetHeight-cabinetDepth)/2, -0))

#remove top face for sink
selectFace(5)
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='ONLY_FACE')

###CREATE TOE KICK###

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")

#create loop cut
region, rv3d, v3d, area = view3d_find(True)

override = {
    'scene'  : bpy.context.scene,
    'region' : region,
    'area'   : area,
    'space'  : v3d
}

#loopCutSlide(1, (0, 0, (cabinetHeight/-2)+(0.0254*3.5)))

bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
    override, 
    MESH_OT_loopcut = {
        "number_cuts"           : 1,
        "smoothness"            : 0,     
        "falloff"               : 'SMOOTH',
        "object_index"          : 0,
        "edge_index"            : 1,
        "mesh_select_mode_init" : (True, False, False)
    }
)

bpy.context.active_object.data.total_vert_sel #select edge loop in middle
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, (cabinetHeight/-2)+(0.0254*3.5)))

bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
    override, 
    MESH_OT_loopcut = {
        "number_cuts"           : 1,
        "smoothness"            : 0,     
        "falloff"               : 'SMOOTH',
        "object_index"          : 0,
        "edge_index"            : 7,
        "mesh_select_mode_init" : (True, False, False)
    }
)

bpy.context.active_object.data.total_vert_sel #select edge loop in middle
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, ((cabinetDepth/-2)+(3*0.0254)), 0))

#extrude toe kick into mesh and merge verts
selectFace(5)
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"use_normal_flip":False, "use_dissolve_ortho_edges":False, "mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, -3*0.0254), "orient_axis_ortho":'X', "orient_type":'NORMAL', "orient_matrix":((-0, 0, 1), (-1, -0, 0), (0, -1, 0)), "orient_matrix_type":'NORMAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":True, "snap_elements":{'VERTEX'}, "use_snap_project":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "use_snap_self":True, "use_snap_edit":True, "use_snap_nonedit":True, "use_snap_selectable":False, "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "view2d_edge_pan":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})

mergeVerts()
deleteVert(0), deleteVert(3)
#remove extra verts 
"""
selectVert(0)
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='VERT')
selectVert(3)
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='VERT')
"""

selectFace(10) #deletion of vertices changes indices two ways, reassigning face index values and breaking code.
```

What can I do to fix this?